# How do I prevent a div from page breaks?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I have the following problem when I print a HTML page with Google Chrome:

[image]

### My HTML + CSS

I'm not sure if [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/jeu77hcd/) is useful for testing printing options.

In the following, please note that I use `page-break-inside: avoid;` for the tiles. And they still get broken in Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit). (Just tested: Works in Firefox)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Div break sample</title>
  <style>
    .content {
      grid-area: content;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-auto-flow: row;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #444;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .tile {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 320px;
      padding: 2.5vh 2.5vw;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      page-break-after: always;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    @media print {
      @page {
        size: auto;
        margin: 0mm;
      }
      .content {
        grid-area: content;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-auto-flow: row;
      }
      .tile {
        height: auto;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="tile">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @GolezTrol What do you want to tell me? Did you see that I use `page-break-inside: avoid`?

Comment: Should be supported in most browsers, at least `page-break-inside: avoid;` that you are using. [See CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break). Not too sure about this `@page` thing, though. I've never used it, but looking at examples, I doubt if you should nest your `.tile` in it. If you want to use that for print only, you should nest it in `@media print {`. The `@page` selector seems to be just for setting page properties, like margins. -edit-, I see you're doing both. Nevermind, I'll shut up now. ;-)

Comment: Maybe you can also experiment with [page-break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) and [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) (to tell the browser explicitly where to break the page), not only [page-break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) (`avoid` seems more like a hint). Also have a look at [`@media` CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), specifically for [paged mediums](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media).